# JSP not receiving AJAX response from Servlet

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple jsp page that sends an ajax request to a servlet and awaits a response. Unfortunately, it's not receiving the response after many attempts. The ajax requests are being transmitted but response isn't being received.

As of now, I have a dropdown in my page and a textbox. I am trying to get the value selected in the dropdown to be printed in the textbox on the dropdown's "onchange" event.
Here's my code. Any help regarding this would be very welcome.

JSP PAGE

```
 <script>            
 function ajaxrequest(){ return new XMLHttpRequest();}        
 function ac()
   {
     var myajaxrequest = new ajaxrequest();
     if(myajaxrequest==null){alert("AJAX NOT WORKING");}         
     else
       {
         alert("AJAX WORKING");                 
         var ind2=document.getElementById("dd1").value;
         myajaxrequest.onreadystatechange=connection;                   
         myajaxrequest.open("GET", "../ajaxservlet?dd1="+ind2,true );
         myajaxrequest.send(null);
       }
    }

 function connection()  
   {               
     if(myajaxrequest.readyState==4)  
        {  
          var x=myajaxrequest.responseText; 
          document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = x;
        }  
   }  
 </script>
 <body>
   <form id = "form1" name ="form1" >
      <select id="dd1" name="dd1" onchange= "ac()">
        <option>Please select </option>
        <option>ankur</option>
        <option>akshay</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" id="result" name="result" /> 
   </form>
 </body>
```

SERVLET :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws     ServletException, IOException {

  System.out.println("hitting servlet");
  String abc = request.getParameter("dd1");
  System.out.println(abc);
  PrintWriter pw=response.getWriter();  
  response.setContentType("text/html");  
  pw.println(abc);
  }
```

The values selected in the dropdown are getting printed in the console but aren't being transmitted back.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myajaxrequest` is local to the `ac()` function since you've used the `var` keyword. You cannot access it in the `connection()` function.

Try declaring your `connection()` function within `ac()` itself.

Instead of checking the status of `readyState`, using XHR level 2, you can simply attach a handler to the `onload` event.

BTW, if native `XHR` isn't supported `ajaxrequest()` will throw an error; it won't return null.

Comment: Thanks. I changed my function ac() to this

function ac()
 {
    var ind2=document.getElementById("dd1").value;
    $.ajax({ type: "GET",   
      url: "../ajaxservlet?dd1="+ind2,   
      success : function(text)
       {
         document.getElementById("result").value= text;
       }
     });
   }

It works now.

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing `myajaxrequest` globally.